# Странное поведение nginx + php7.0-fpm на Ubuntu 16.04. Что это может быть?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, php7, php-fpm

Странности проявляются в следующем:
- сайт работает какое-либо время, время всегда разное, работает достаточно шустро и без проблем
- спустя какое то время *26481 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream по логам Nginxa
- ребутим php-fpm и все заново начинает работать нормально до следующего раза
конфиги хоста в nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
 server {
        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 128M;

        autoindex on;
  server_tokens off;

        listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;  
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000";
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;   

  location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300;
                proxy_send_timeout   600;
                proxy_read_timeout   600;
                proxy_buffer_size    64k;
                proxy_buffers     16 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_hide_header  Vary;
                proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding '';
                proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
                proxy_set_header   Referer $http_referer;
                proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
                proxy_set_header   Cookie $http_cookie;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

  #ENABLE GZIP
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level 5;

  #ENABLE BROWSER CACHE
  location ~* ^.+\.(woff|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf)$ {
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}
```

в настройках fpm/www.conf ничего не менялось кроме

```
;listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

в slow логе fpm после краша пишет

```
script_filename = /var/www/frontend/current/web/index.php
[0x00007f03902127d0] curl_exec() /var/www/frontend/releases/20170707092052/models/WorkApi.php:61
[0x00007f03902126c0] requestToApi() /var/www/frontend/releases/20170707092052/controllers/MainController.php:104
[0x00007f03902125d0] getUserLocation() /var/www/frontend/releases/20170707092052/controllers/MainController.php:48
[0x00007f03902124b0] beforeAction() /var/www/frontend/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:152
[0x00007f03902123a0] runAction() /var/www/frontend/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:454
[0x00007f0390212280] runAction() /var/www/frontend/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:84
[0x00007f0390212190] handleRequest() /var/www/frontend/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php:375
[0x00007f03902120f0] run() /var/www/frontend/releases/20170707092052/web/index.php:30
```

Тюнинговать fpm и тайм ауйты пробовал. Результата не дало.
Кто может сталкивался с таким, как победили? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Что может быть

1) Ошибка программирования, которая приводит к сбою php-fpm. Обычно остаются следы в логах. Возможно вы как-то не так обращаетесь с curl.

2) По какой-то причине PHP не может записать файл сессий. Причина - неправильный доступ к директории сессий или же заполнен диск.

3) Какое-то расширение падает с ошибкой и тянет за собой php-fpm. Это может быть APC, memcache/d, и т.д. Такую ошибку сложно отдебажить.

Comment: можно ли как то настроить fpm так, чтобы он не падал в случае ошибки?

Comment: @ДенисНейчев эм.. supervisor? падать всё равно будет, но supervisor будет его сразу-же поднимать обратно